# How can I run from an agent to another agent running on a different domino server?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, hcl

**Brief description**

We do have multiple Domino Servers (`DS`). Each `DS` is hosting several maildatabases. I would like to delete specific mail database. The deletion process gets triggered by an external application, which can run `DS` agents. The external application can also pass parameters to the agent.

**Infrastructure overview**

I have 1 notes database (`ND`) called `delete-database.nsf`. This `ND` is replicated with 3 Domino Servers (`DS`), lets call them `DS1`, `DS2` and `DS3`.

**Workflow**

The external application will run the `agent1` on `DS1` with the parameters mailserver and mailfilename. Let's say the mailserver-parameter-value is `DS2` and mailfilename-parameter is `mail\doe.nsf` .

Due to I can't delete a mail database which is not on same `DS` like the agent is currently running, I'm calling `agent2` on replica database (based on mailserver-paramter) and also passing the mailfilename.

`Agent2` should receive the malfilename-parameter and delete the maildatabase, which is located on the same `DS` like itself.

**Question**

How can I call from `agent1` on `DS1` another agent called `agent2` on `DS2` and also pass parameters like mailfilename.

I tried this, but it doesn't call the agent2 and also not passing the parameters.

Code of `agent1`:

```
Dim ses As New NotesSession
Dim db2 As NotesDatabase
Dim agent2 As NotesAgent
Dim docTemp As NotesDocument
    
Set db2 = New NotesDatabase( "DS2/Certifier", "delete-database.nsf" )
Set agent2 = db2.GetAgent( "agent2" )
    
Set docTemp = New NotesDocument( db2 )

' Parameters
docTemp.mailfilename = "mail\doe.nsf"
    
Call agent2.runWithDocumentContext( docTemp )
```

Code of `agent2`:

```
Dim ses As New NotesSession
Dim docTemp As NotesDocument
Dim description As String
Dim mailserver As String
Dim mailfilename As String

Set docTemp = ses.DocumentContext

mailfilename = docTemp.mailfilename

' * Delete mail file part *
' * ... *
' * Delete mail file part *
```

Comment: If the databases are replicas, just create a document in the database.  The document will get replicated to all the other servers  When the agent runs (on whatever server) it checks a view to see if any documents are waiting for it to act on.  You'd probably want to add security, like a readers field or a signature (or both) though.

Comment: Thank you, its a completly new way to solve this issue. Never did it before, so I have to find out how the code would look like. But for better understanding, whats the background idea of the additional security with readers field and signature? Do you have some more information/explanation?

Comment: The built-in NotesAdministrationProcess.DeleteReplicas feature that @Tode described in his answer to your other question is really a better way to do this.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz OK. But what I wonder is, for example the agent runs on Domino Server 1 with NotesAdministrationProcess.DeleteReplicas. But the mail database is located on Domino Server 2 and doesn't have any replica to other Domino Server. Will this work? I mean, the big challange is, to do the deletion for maildatabases, which or not on the same domino server like the agent.

Comment: Notes/Domino has been around for more than 30 years. Many, many organizations have faced the issue of efficiently deleting mail databases. The adminp process was invented to make things like this easier. It will replicate deletion requests to the other servers through the shared admin4.nsf database, and each server will process the request. If everything is set up correctly, this will work. Of course, there will be a delay. The first server has to figure out what servers it needs to send requests to. Then there will be replication in the next cycle. Then the servers will do the deletes.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest method is to send the other database an internal mail, with all the info you need. In the other db you create an agent that runs on When mail has arrived, checks whether it comes from the right source, and then executes whatever you need. You only have to set your db up as a mail-in database.